# Request to implement ABCjs arpeggio symbol (and a note regarding other decorations)

Tags: feature-request, abcjs

A question regarding the [interpretation of a vertical arpeggio symbol](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104445/arpeggiated-chords-with-partial-wavy-vertical-lines) revealed that the SE ABCjs implementation does not render the arpeggio decoration. (An answer attempted to use it.)

For example, this code...

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1/1
!arpeggio![CEG]
```

...produces this in SE, ...

```
X:0
K:none
M:none
L:1/1
!arpeggio![CEG]
```

...but should produce this (from the [abcjs editor](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html)).
[image: abcjs arpeggio decoration]

Allowing this could be a bug, but treating as a feature request.

---

There are other ABCjs decorations not rendered by SE. I list them as an FYI and "nice to have", but the ABCjs editor (linked above) also does not render them.

```
!trill(!      (this and the next would be most used, I suspect)  
!trill)!      (this and the previous would be most used, I suspect)  
!turnx!  
!invertedturn!  
!invertedturnx!  
!D.S.!       (this could be readily worked around)  
!D.C.!       (this could be readily worked around)  
!dacoda!     (I believe this can be worked around)
!dacapo!     (I believe this can be worked around)
```

Comment: I still wish they'd incorporated LilyPond, but I'm not tech-savvy enough to know why they decided it wasn't feasible. I still have yet to use ABCjs; I just use LilyPond and post the image files.

Comment: @Richard This is not a problem with the language, but with the implementation. Your lilypond implementation might have 1000 times more bugs than this abc implementation, so be careful with what you ask! That said, what you remember was like 5 years ago, maybe there's a new implementation of lilypond that the admins like? Maybe we can have both abc and lilypond now? Like SE, that supports different renders for different languages.

Comment: @VonHuffman Good point. I should clarify that it's not that I think ABCjs is flawed in any way, I just don't really see it used outside of this context. As such, I've never felt it was worth my time to learn it, especially when I can use LilyPond in so many environments outside of this one.